# how to get the position of user by GPS and if not availabe by Network

Tags: android, gps, location

I am new in android developing, and so intrested in getting location of users!!!!!

You may know that we can access users location by two types:

**GPS** *(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATON)*
**Network based** *(ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)*

My Question is:

> I Want to get the location(latittude & longitude) of user by GPS. **But, if the user has turned GPS Off/GPS isn't supported, then i want to get user's location by Network, or, Network-based location**

.

Hope you understood my question....
Any help is accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
 LocationManager mlocManager; 
        mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
                    mlocListener = new MyLocationListener(); 
        //if condition to check if GPS is available 
if (mlocManager                   .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {                         mlocManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                                mlocListener, null); 
                    } 
       else if (mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) { 
                        mlocManager.requestSingleUpdate( 
                                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, mlocListener, null); 
                    } 


        //this is the class to get the location. 
            public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener { 

                @Override 
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                    try { 
    //you may store these values where ever required.  
                        Double latitude =  location.getLatitude();      
                        Double longitude =  location.getLongitude(); 
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } 

                } 

                @Override 
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

                } 

                @Override 
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

                } 

                @Override 
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

                } 

            }
```

Comment: **It is showing error: Cannot Resolve symbol - mlocListner.....** Any Ideas??????

Answer (score 1):

When you use the [FusedLocationProviderApi](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html) as used in the [getting the last known location training](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) and [receiving location updates training](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html), it will automatically fall back to network location if GPS is not available.

Comment: Can you provide me code? I am very new in android developing. @ianhanniballake

Comment: Both the training docs I linked to include all the code you'd need.

Answer (score 1):

Hope get GPS code helps you.

```
    if (Common.getIsGPSEnabled()) {
        final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) c.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locationListener;
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {  
                myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);  
                Toast.makeText(c, "location changed, My location is removed to"
                + myLocation.getLatitude()+","+myLocation.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                Latitude = myLocation.getLatitude(); 
                Longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
          };
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, (long)0, (float)0, locationListener); 
        myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
        if(myLocation != null)
        { 
               ///
        }
    }
```